# Android paging with swipe to refresh inside CoordinatorLayout getting error

Tags: android, paging, android-coordinatorlayout, swiperefreshlayout

recyclerview consistency error one first refresh working properly on second refresh getting error. no line number in stack.

```
    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:aapt="http://schemas.android.com/aapt"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/parent_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:background="@color/white_color">
    <androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
            android:id="@+id/swipe_refresh_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"

            android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/rvPost"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:clipToPadding="false"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:paddingTop="19dp"
                app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
                app:spanCount="3" />
        </androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

SwipeRefreshLayout   swipeRefreshLayout = getView().findViewById(R.id.swipe_refresh_layout);
        swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {
                viewModel.refresh();
            }
        });
```

Adapter Code

```
class DiscoverAdapter(private val action: (b: Int?) -> Unit)
    : PagedListAdapter<PostModel, RecyclerView.ViewHolder>(NewsDiffCallback) {

    private val DATA_VIEW_TYPE = 1
    private val FOOTER_VIEW_TYPE = 2

    private var state = State.LOADING

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        return if (viewType == DATA_VIEW_TYPE) DiscoverViewHolder.create(parent) else ListFooterViewHolder.create(parent)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        if (getItemViewType(position) == DATA_VIEW_TYPE)
            (holder as DiscoverViewHolder).bind(action, getItem(position))
        else (holder as ListFooterViewHolder).bind(action, state)
    }

    override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int {
        return if (position < super.getItemCount()) DATA_VIEW_TYPE else FOOTER_VIEW_TYPE
    }

    companion object {
        val NewsDiffCallback = object : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<PostModel>() {
            override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: PostModel, newItem: PostModel): Boolean {
                return oldItem.id == newItem.id
            }

            override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: PostModel, newItem: PostModel): Boolean {
                return oldItem == newItem
            }
        }
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return super.getItemCount() + if (hasFooter()) 1 else 0
    }

    private fun hasFooter(): Boolean {
        return super.getItemCount() != 0 && (state == State.LOADING || state == State.ERROR)
    }

    fun setState(state: State) {
        this.state = state
        notifyItemChanged(super.getItemCount())
    }

    fun getData(position: Int): PostModel {
        return getItem(position) as PostModel
    }
}
```

View Holder 1 is items and another use for load more data

```
class DiscoverViewHolder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {

    fun bind(retry: (x: Int?) -> Unit, postModel: PostModel?) {
        val width = DeviceScreenUtil.getInstance().width
        val newWidth = width / 3
        val layoutParams = itemView.rl_main_layout.getLayoutParams()
        layoutParams.height = Math.round(newWidth * 1.2f)
        layoutParams.width = Math.round(newWidth.toFloat())
        itemView.rl_main_layout.setPadding(3, 3, 4, 4)
        itemView.rl_main_layout.setLayoutParams(layoutParams)

        if (postModel != null) {
//            itemView.tv_total_like.text = news.title
            if (!postModel.thumbnail.isNullOrEmpty())
                Picasso.get().load(postModel.thumbnail).into(itemView.iv_image)
            itemView.setOnClickListener { retry(adapterPosition) }
            if (postModel.likes > 0) itemView.tv_total_like.setText(postModel.likes.toString() + "")
        }
    }

    companion object {
        fun create(parent: ViewGroup): DiscoverViewHolder {
            val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
                    .inflate(R.layout.item_myprofile, parent, false)
            return DiscoverViewHolder(view)
        }
    }
}
```

set adapter code

```
DiscoverAdapter discoverAdapter = DiscoverAdapter {
        if (it == null) {
            viewModel.retry()
        } else {
            click(it)
        }

    }
    rvPost.adapter = discoverAdapter
    viewModel.newsList.observe(this,
            Observer {
                discoverAdapter.submitList(it)
            })
```

invalidating datasource on refresh

Error Logs

java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Inconsistency detected. Invalid item position 20(offset:20).state:21 androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView{ecd9c90 VFED..... .F....ID 0,0-704,1024 #7f08021d app:id/rvPost}, adapter:com.app.ui.main.dashboard.search.discover.adapter.DiscoverAdapter@a9fb989, layout:androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager@97fed8e, context:com.app.ui.main.dashboard.MainActivity@226aa34
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:6183)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:6118)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:6114)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2303)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager.layoutChunk(GridLayoutManager.java:561)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1587)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:665)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(GridLayoutManager.java:170)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep1(RecyclerView.java:4085)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3849)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:4404)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16651)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5440)
        at androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout.onLayout(SwipeRefreshLayout.java:625)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16651)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5440)
        at com.google.android.material.appbar.HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.layoutChild(HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.java:148)
        at com.google.android.material.appbar.ViewOffsetBehavior.onLayoutChild(ViewOffsetBehavior.java:43)
        at com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior.onLayoutChild(AppBarLayout.java:1892)
        at androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onLayout(CoordinatorLayout.java:918)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16651)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5440)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:336)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:273)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16651)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5440)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.onLayout(ConstraintLayout.java:1915)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16651)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5440)
        at com.google.android.material.appbar.HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.layoutChild(HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.java:148)
        at com.google.android.material.appbar.ViewOffsetBehavior.onLayoutChild(ViewOffsetBehavior.java:43)
        at com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior.onLayoutChild(AppBarLayout.java:1892)
        at androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onLayout(CoordinatorLayout.java:918)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16651)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5440)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:336)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:273)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16651)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5440)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1743)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1586)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1495)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16651)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5440)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:336)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:273)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16651)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5440)
        at androi

Comment: If you provide your error log I would probably help you. I've been working on Android Paging Library for the last two weeks and also implemented Pull To Refresh. Provide your DataSource and LiveData setup for PagedList.

Comment: please check question i resubmited error log

Comment: It has nothing to do with `SwipeRefreshLayout` or `CoordinatorLayout` or anything with the layout, the error is Index Out of Bounds which means wherever you're working on a `List` or an `ArrayList`, you're trying to access data on a position which doesn't exist in the list itself. So, provide the code.

Answer (score 0):

problem exist in recyclerview adapter i think you forget to adapte.rnotifyDataChanged() when set data again after refresh :)

plz print your adapter code

Comment: im using paging adapter. and i think notify is not required in pagingadapter. livedata observer set data to recyclerview auto;

Comment: please print your submitList method

Comment: - livedata will observe when data change in your context in activity or fragment


- livedata  will submit list to your adapter


-  but list in adapter is different object list and adapter need to know that list has been changed so use notify data change method in adapter must be called 
you are fully understand of live data but what about adapter ? do u got it